# Is it possible to export the file history timeline in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to export the file-save history of one or more files as a text file, possibly csv.

For example: I'd like to ideally select a file or group of files in the file explorer, or select a time-range in a file's the timeline panel, then export that as a summary in csv form, ie:

```
file name, time-stamp
file name, time-stamp etc
```

Can't find functionality for this. Perhaps an extension exists?

[image]

Comment: use a bunch of `git log` commands and process the output if you can't find the correct options

Comment: riov8 thanks but the file saves are interim to any git commits

Comment: you only have a TIMELINE view when there is a git repo, do you want a log of every time you press `Ctrl+S`, where do you expect these timestamps to be saved, what is the point of knowing that I have saved the file every N minutes

Comment: rioV8 yes I have a git repo, but the timeline includes local saves between commits, not just the commits themselves. When you click on a timeline entry (see picture) a comparison (diff) between the clicked item and the previous save comes up in the editor, with time and date saved in title tab. So the information is there. The reason why I want consolidated information is so I can monitor file activity so I can document my work done and time spent on it efficiently (outside of any git context).

Comment: Probably I should just make this a feature request.

Comment: do you have some kind of history extension installed, or is this a feature of a new VSC version (I don't use the latest), I save a lot so that means I would get a huge history database with useless information and my disk gets to store more junk

Comment: what if you spent the whole day debugging to find the problem, you don't edit any file just use the debugger, a whole day not recorded, what if you type for 4 hours and only save once a day, or type 10 min and save once a day, how would you extract that you have worked 4 hours or 10 min. How do you record the time spent before the first save of the day. What if you cross the day border and make an all nighter.

Comment: The timeline is a feature, not an extension, since earlier this year. I only use it to estimate time spent when I don't have a chance to document it otherwise.

Comment: as I read the release notes the content of the history is saved in the workspace, I don't know if it is in the actual workspace or the workspace meta data stored in the VSC background storage.

Comment: there's a History directory and a workspaceStorage directory in:
~/Library/Application Support/Code/User (macos)

Comment: if you can read these files you might extract the timestamps

Comment: thanks, there's no real easy way (for me) to read the files (database files and "staged" copies);  so I'll just put in a feature request

Comment: most likely they are sqlite databases