# Sharing a file that includes its local TIMELINE on VS Code with other people

Tags: visual-studio-code, collaboration

I am a beginner in programming and I have a question regarding the dev tool vscode editor.
I would like to be able to send my files to somebody else including the saving history of the file (TIMELINE, left bar),
how can I do it?

I am currently working on HTML and JS files in a local folder on my computer.

Much obliged.

I tried to google it and in the vscode itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74724726/is-it-possible-to-export-the-file-history-timeline-in-visual-studio-code), there are no way to export TIMELINE so I believed that you cannot do such operation.

However, if you want collaborate a programming project with others, you may consider using git.